# Select middle value in array - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to make sure that the middle value Lists is the first view that is seen when building my application. Xcode offers `if let firstView = viewList.first` and `if let firstView = viewList.last` but I can't workout how to select the middle value.

```
lazy var viewList:[UIViewController] = {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let lists = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Lists")
    let reminders = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Reminders")
    let todo = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "To Do")

    return [reminders, lists, todo]
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.dataSource = self

    if let firstView = viewList.first {
        self.setViewControllers([firstView], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `viewList` declared as `[UIViewController]` (not as optionals - `[UIViewController?]`), you don't have to "optional binding" (checking the whether the element is `nil` or not) because it *has to* be exist. what you should do instead is to check if the index in the range (making sure that the index is in the range).

Logically speaking (obviously), if you are pretty sure that `viewList` *always* has 3 elements, there is no need to do any check, just:

```
let middleViewController = viewList[1]
```

In case of the number of elements in `viewList` is undetermined and you are aiming to get the middle element, you simply get it as:

```
let middleViewController = viewList[(viewList.count - 1) / 2]
```

Remember, `first` and `last` are optionals, in your case there is no need to work with optionals...

Answer (score 8):

Similar to `first` and `last`, you can extend `Array` with a computed `middle` property that returns an optional `Element`.

```
extension Array {

    var middle: Element? {
        guard count != 0 else { return nil }

        let middleIndex = (count > 1 ? count - 1 : count) / 2
        return self[middleIndex]
    }

}
```

---

Usage Example:

```
if let middleView = viewList.middle {
    //... Do something
}
```

---

I want you to be aware that `first` and `last` can return the same element if the array has only 1 element.

Similarly, though this extension will work for any array length, it can return the same element for:

- `first`, `middle` & `last` if your array has only 1 element
- `middle` & `last` if your array has only 2 elements

Answer (score 3):

Can add an extension to `Array` to accomplish this:

```
extension Array {

    var middleIndex: Int {
        return (self.isEmpty ? self.startIndex : self.count - 1) / 2
    }
}
```

```
let myArray: [String] = ["Hello", "World", "!"]
print("myArray.middleIndex: \(myArray.middleIndex)") // prints 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `viewList` is an array of type `UIViewController`. And `first` and `last` only denotes their 0th and last index. like:

> `viewList.first` is same as `viewList[0]`
>
> `viewList.last` is same as `viewList[viewList.count - 1]`
>
> Only difference in using these are if you will use `viewList.first` it will return `nil` if your array is empty, but if you will use `viewList[0]` on empty array, you app will be crash with error **index out of bound...**

**So, you can easily access your middle value with index as:**

```
if viewList.count > 1 {
    let middleView = viewList[1]
    self.setViewControllers([middleView], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**If you are not sure about the `viewList.count` will be 3 or more, Then:**

```
    let middleIndex = (viewList.count - 1) / 2
    let middleView = viewList[middleIndex]
```

Comment: You can't, `viewList[1]` is *not* an optional, It would be legal if `viewList` was declared as `[UIViewController?]`.

Comment: Thanks @AhmadF for highlighting it, I was just depicting same code. Btw I update my answer.